# Table view controller background from the table to the title bar when scrolling down the tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a question about the background that appears on the screen when the user taps on a tableview and scroll the table down. In my case when doing this, a brilliant white background appears from the top side of the table to the title bar. I have searched in the attributes inspector but nothing found that could change this white background. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean ?? sorry but i can not get you, please elaborate your question with image. thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean the background of the UITableView? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: It's clear. The question is about the background color of the table you see above the 1st row when you pull down on the table exposing the area above the 1st row.

Comment: Yes @iPatel, of course, please imagine a normal table view with a title bar. If you tap on any part of the table (e.g. on a cell) and move the table down, like scrolling the table, the title bar stays at the top of the view and the table scrolls down, between both elements, the table that is scrolling down and the title bar that stays on the top, there appears a surface, in my case it is always brilliant white. What I want to know if it is possible to change this background, with an image or with another colour

Comment: You are right @rmaddy, you have explained it better than me, the area between the 1st row and the title bar while pulling down the table.

Comment: Thank you @iPatel, it works as expected. Would you mind putting your proposal in an answer? I would be glad accepting your answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set backGround color or image of `UITableView` by using this  following code

```
UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(229/255.f) green:(248/255.f) blue:(232/255.f) alpha:1.0f]; //For set Image [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableBGImage.png"]];          
self.tblView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tblView.bounds];                     
self.tblView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```